# Link's clickable area only on text, not on full row

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

My app shows a list of posts (title+data) in a set of rows. The title is aligned to the left of the row and the date to the right, there is some blank space between them. Something like:

**Title 1 _______________ Date 1**

**Title 2 _______________ Date 2**

**...etc**

I am trying to "cover" with a link all the blank space, not only the title and the date, but when I hover the blank with the mouse I get no response. If I go hover the title or date I get the link response for my browser.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time.

I have this in my html.erb:

```
    <div class="post" id="<%= post.name %>">    
    <a href="<%= post_path(post) %>">
            <span class="title"><%= post.title %></span>
            <span class="date"><%= post.created_at.to_date.strftime("%b %e") %></span>
    </a>  
    </div>
```

And this in my css.scss:

```
.post {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width:  900px;
height: 40px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #BDBDBD;}

.title {  font-size: 2.1em;}

.date {  float: right;  margin-right: 40px;  margin-top: 10px; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can improve your rails code by passing a block to link_to

```
<div class="post" id="<%= post.name %>">
    <a href="<%= post_path(post) %>">
        <span class="title"><%= post.title %></span>
        <span class="date"><%= post.created_at.to_date.strftime("%b %e") %></span>
    </a>  
</div>
```

Should be

```
<div class="post" id="<%= post.name %>">
<%= link_to post_path(post) do %>
    <span class="title"><%= post.title %></span>
    <span class="date"><%= post.created_at.to_date.strftime("%b %e") %></span>
<% end %>
</div>
```

And now, about your question itself:
Since anchors are inline elements by default, when you wrap other inline elements with an anchor, it doesn't behave as you are expecting. In order to work as a block wrapper you need to add:

```
.post a{ display:block;}
```

To your css.

I also sugest you use fluid values in your .post width (so devices with width narrower than 900px still can render same expected layout), but that's up to you.

see this fiddle to check how it looks https://jsfiddle.net/ovxh94k7/3/

Comment: if your .title and .date styles looks  overriden by some of the  styles of the anchor tag you should consider explicitly declare them inside `.post a{ display:block; }` for example:`.post a{ display:block; text-decoration:none}` please see this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ovxh94k7/4/

Comment: Many thanks, your examples are very ilustrative and help me a lot with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use `a { display: block; }`.

Obviously use a class to select only the links you want displayed like this, otherwise all links on your site will have their display behavior changed.

By default, an anchor tag has `display: inline` defined, meaning that it should be rendered as a text element.  The interactive areas for elements defined as `display: inline` (unsurprisingly) are the text areas.  Changing it to display as a block element changes the element's box model; the clickable areas change as well to be more in line with what you would expect from a div.

Comment: Many thanks, that works. I defined the a{display: block;} inside .post and the row is now all clickable.

The thing is the link style defined in a{}, now applies to .title and .date text as well. 

How could I set, for example, different font colors for the classes inside the one where the link style is defined? 

I mean, in this particular case, how could I custom text inside .title & .date, besides the link format defined in .post?